# How does one manage external resources in a SOLID way?

Tags: c#, testing, abstraction, solid-principles

I'm currently working on a project where I'm parsing an external file to an abstracted object like so:

```
public interface IMapConverter
{
    IMap Convert(IMapFile file);
}

public interface IMapFile
{
    void Load(string filePath);
    string Json { get; }
}
```

My plan was to abstract the loading of the file by using the IMapFile implementation and creating the StreamReader inside that implementation. I would then pass that on to the IMapConverter.Convert method. Would that be a correct approach and maintain testability? Would it for example be wrong to pass the string directly to the IMapConverter and handle it there?

Comment: It's not clear. To me `IMapFile` seems like a bad abstraction as `Json` is probably an implementation detail. Do all mapping files contain json only? What is the role of the `IMapConverter`? Is it only parsing the json string into a `Map`? It seems that your abstractions are a bit odd and you would probably benefit from a more explicit design that attempts to be less flexible than using abstractions that fails to be flexible. Could you explain the problem you are trying to solve in more details?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Of course! An IMapFile would load a file, which could contain a string or binary data or anything (I see what you mean now). The IMapConverter would converty any format and parse it to an IMap object which contains the actual map data which is then passed on to the MapRenderer. What abstraction would you suggest instead?

Comment: I need more information to propose better abstractions. What exactly is an `IMap`? Is it a form of dictionary data structure or `Map` is a business concept in your domain? Will there be multiple implementations of such `Map`? What are the dependencies of a `Map`? Is the creation process complex? Did you plan to have multiple converter implementations? What is the role of the converter?

Comment: `IMap` is indeed a business concept. It's the result of the converted `IMapFile` to `IMap` by the `IMapConverter`. The `IMapConverter` reads all the data out of the file that is interesting the to map of the game: layers, tiles etc. There would will be only one or two implementions of the `IMapConverter`, for `IMap` this would be one. What do you mean with the creation process?

Comment: Is it important from your business perspective that maps are stored in files? Why not just having a `IMapRepository`? `mapRepsitory.save(map)`, `mapRepository.findByName(someMapName)`. You could then implement a `FileMapRepository`. I would also get rid of the `IMap` interface. A `Map` is probably an entity and it is rather rare that you have multiple implementations of the same kind of entity and when you do then you probably have a base class and use inheritance. A `Map` should also not be mocked in unit testing, so I see no use for having an `IMap` interface.

Comment: I think the repository pattern might be a good solution. I would only be loading maps and not saving them and I would still have to handle the parsing of the map file, thus parsing a file path. Would the repository pattern help in abstracting the loading of the file?

Comment: Yeah, definitely. The important part is to abstract that maps are saved in a file from the domain perspective. Therefore, the repository public interface shouldn't have anything related to files. Obviously, the `FileMapRepository` will have to deal with such things internally and may rely on additionnal collaborator objects to do so (e.g parser for different map formats). You may use the ISP principle and have an interface like `ILoadMaps` rather than `MapRepository`. That will give you the ability to have `ISaveMaps` eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with doing what you're suggesting, i.e. having the concrete `IMapConverter` create an instance of your concrete `IMapFile` because they're both on the same layer of your application.

The rule, as I understand it, is that one class that implements a dependency interface can "know" about an implementation of another interface as long as they're on the same layer of your application; once you're working between layers, you want to inject your dependencies, i.e. your concrete implementations, into the layer below it.

I've been studying [the onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) which I would highly recommend to anyone who is looking to create loosely-coupled, highly-testable applications.  This notion of dependencies knowing about one another as long as they're on the same layer is discussed on that site.

Comment: Very clear! Thanks for linking to the onion architecture, a good read!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.